# Замена на пробел в js

Tags: javascript

В js не силён, гугл выдает, как заменит пробелы, а вот как эти пробелы вставить, ничего толкового не нашёл.

Суть задачи: надо в тексте конструкцию `<SP>` заменить на пробелы.

Comment: @pmx, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2nz0stdt/

Comment: спасибо огромное, пробовал так replace(/<SP>/g, ' ') и не мого понять почему не работает, а теперь когда ткнули носом дошло ))